# Nightmare JS not loading picture (lazyload)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

I am trying to scrape a Crunchbase profile with Nightmare JS. The textual information (e.g. website) works great, but it is not loading the Company Profile Picture in the Electron Window. The output of 'img_url' is `'<div _ngcontent-sc247="" lazyloadimage="" style="width:100%;height:100%;" class="provide-styling"></div>'`, which probably means that the current tag is only a placeholder until the real image has loaded but even setting up the waiting time to 30000 was not helping. Any ideas on how to make the image load?

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({
    show: true
});

nightmare
    .goto('https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/celonis')
    .scrollTo(10,10)
    .wait(5000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        return {          
            'website': document.querySelectorAll('.icon_and_value li')[4].querySelector('label-with-icon span a').href,
            'img_url': document.querySelector('identifier-image').innerHTML
        }
    })
    .end()
    .then(function(dict) {
        console.log(dict)
    })
```

Comment: Crunch base has an API, it may be easier to get the data you want through that. https://data.crunchbase.com/docs/using-the-api

Comment: The Crunchbase API costs multiple thousands per year, so would be great to solve this another way